# HTML statement not seen in mail when send using SQL Server

Tags: html, sql, sql-server

I have a procedure which will generate the email in my outlook inbox. The mail is coming in my inbox but only the title of the mail is appearing where all other are coming as blank.

I have the table SQL statement whose statement is:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[Datareceipt],1),
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[DataLoad Start],1),
    Deliverables,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[Original ETA],1),
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[Current ETA],1),
    CASE WHEN [estimated PercentComplete] < 100 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),[estimated PercentComplete]) ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),[estimated PercentComplete]) END,
    [Delievered],
    CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[DateDelievered],1) IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[DateDelievered],1) END,
    CASE WHEN [TurnaroundTime] IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),[TurnaroundTime]) END,
    CASE WHEN [ELO] IS NULL THEN '' ELSE [ELO] END    
FROM HAPDPGroupTracker.dbo.ActivityReport_Weekly
```

The output of this query is:

[image]

I want this table as output in my body while sending the mail. So, I added in the `txt` variable as and converted it into HTML body:

```
-- Table Body

    SELECT
    '<tr>'
    + '<td align="center">' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[Datareceipt]) + '</td>'
    + '<td align="center">' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[DataLoad Start],1) +'</td>'
    + '<td align="center">' + Deliverables + '</td>'
    + '<td align="center">' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[Original ETA],1)+ '</td>'
    + '<td align="center">' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[Current ETA],1) + '</td>'
    + '<td align="center"' + CASE WHEN [estimated PercentComplete] < 100 THEN '>' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[estimated PercentComplete]) + '%' + '</td>'ELSE' bgcolor="#abdda4">' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[estimated PercentComplete]) + '%' END + '</td>'
    + '<td align="center">' + [Delievered] + '</td>'
    + '<td align="center">' + CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[DateDelievered],1) IS NULL THEN '' + '</td>' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[DateDelievered],1) END + '</td>'
    + '<td align="center">' + CASE WHEN [TurnaroundTime] IS NULL THEN '' + '</td>' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[TurnaroundTime]) END + '</td>'
    + '<td align="center">' + CASE WHEN [ELO] IS NULL THEN '' ELSE [ELO] END + '</td>'
    + '</tr align="center">' AS ActivityReport,
    RowId = IDENTITY (INT,1,1)
    INTO dbo.#Tem
    FROM CADGroup.dbo.ActivityReport_Weekly
    SET @Ctr = 1
    SELECT @RowCt = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.#Temprint @RowCtWHILE @Ctr <= @RowCt
    BEGIN
    SELECT @RecTxt = ActivityReport FROM dbo.#Tem WHERE RowId = @Ctr
    SET @Txt += @RecTxt
    SET @Ctr += 1
    END
    print @Txt
    SET @Txt += '</table><br><br><br>'DROP TABLE dbo.#TemSET @Txt += 'Thanks.'
```

My full procedure code goes here:

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[ActivityReport_After_Load]
AS
--- Update Variables--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @AuditName VARCHAR(100) = 'PAP'
DECLARE @Cc VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT [Cc] FROM CADGroup.dbo._MailingList WHERE StoredProc = 'ActivityReports');

BEGIN TRY
SET @Subject = @AuditName + ' Data Load Activity Report: Weekly ' + FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyy-MM-dd')

SET @Txt = 'Hello All,<br><br>'
SET @Txt += 'The ' + @AuditName + ' data has completed and deploy will run at 6pm(EST time)<br><br>'

-- Table Header
SET @Txt += '<table border="1">'
SET @Txt += '<tr>'
SET @Txt += '<th bgcolor="#6699cc">Data Receipt</th>'
SET @Txt += '<th bgcolor="#6699cc">DataLoad Start</th>'
SET @Txt += '<th bgcolor="#6699cc">Deliverables</th>'
SET @Txt += '<th bgcolor="#6699cc">Original ETA</th>'
SET @Txt += '<th bgcolor="#6699cc">Current ETA</th>'
SET @Txt += '<th bgcolor="#6699cc">Estimated % Complete</th>'
SET @Txt += '<th bgcolor="#6699cc">Delivered?</th>'
SET @Txt += '<th bgcolor="#6699cc">Date Delivered</th>'
SET @Txt += '<th bgcolor="#6699cc">Turnaround Time (days)</th>'
SET @Txt += '<th bgcolor="#6699cc">Early/Late/On Time</th>'
SET @Txt += '</tr>'

-- Table Body
SELECT
'<tr>'
+ '<td align="center">' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[Datareceipt]) + '</td>'
+ '<td align="center">' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[DataLoad Start],1) +'</td>'
+ '<td align="center">' + Deliverables + '</td>'
+ '<td align="center">' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[Original ETA],1)+ '</td>'
+ '<td align="center">' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[Current ETA],1) + '</td>'
+ '<td align="center"' + CASE WHEN [estimated PercentComplete] < 100 THEN '>' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[estimated PercentComplete]) + '%' + '</td>'ELSE' bgcolor="#abdda4">' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[estimated PercentComplete]) + '%' END + '</td>'
+ '<td align="center">' + [Delievered] + '</td>'
+ '<td align="center">' + CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[DateDelievered],1) IS NULL THEN '' + '</td>' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[DateDelievered],1) END + '</td>'
+ '<td align="center">' + CASE WHEN [TurnaroundTime] IS NULL THEN '' + '</td>' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[TurnaroundTime]) END + '</td>'
+ '<td align="center">' + CASE WHEN [ELO] IS NULL THEN '' ELSE [ELO] END + '</td>'
+ '</tr align="center">' AS ActivityReport,
RowId = IDENTITY (INT,1,1)
INTO dbo.#Tem
FROM CADGroup.dbo.ActivityReport_Weekly

SET @Ctr = 1
SELECT @RowCt = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.#Tem

print @RowCt

WHILE @Ctr <= @RowCt
BEGIN
    SELECT @RecTxt = ActivityReport FROM dbo.#Tem WHERE RowId = @Ctr
    SET @Txt += @RecTxt
    SET @Ctr += 1
END
print @Txt
SET @Txt += '</table><br><br><br>'

DROP TABLE dbo.#Tem

SET @Txt += 'Thanks.'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
print @Txt
SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS [Error Message]
    , ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
    , ERROR_NUMBER() AS [Error Number]
    , ERROR_SEVERITY() AS [Error Severity]
    , ERROR_STATE() AS [Error State]
END CATCH

-- Send Email
EXEC Ddly.Mail.SqlNotifySend @Subject, @To, @Cc, NULL, @Txt, @Result OUT, @MailOutput OUT, 0, 1
GO
```

I don't know what is the problem in the `txt` variable. `Subject` is coming properly in my inbox but the content of `txt` is not coming. Also this statement is also not seen in my inbox:

```
SET @Txt = 'Hello All,<br><br>'
SET @Txt += 'The ' + @AuditName + ' data has completed and deploy will run at 6pm(EST time)<br><br>'
```

I am just seeing that content of `txt` is not being printed.

Comment: Without a [mre] its going to be impossible for us to debug that for you. But my guess is you are adding a null value to you `@txt` variable which means it will always be null.

Comment: I expect you have `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON` in effect. `Delievered` is `null` which will cause `@Txt` to become `null`. Have you tried placing a few defensive `ISNULL()` function calls?

Comment: yes you are correct @AlwaysLearning .please put ans separately so i can tick

Comment: Was this written in 1998? The HTML is way out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have [`SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-concat-null-yields-null-transact-sql) in effect.

In your example query and result you showed that the `Delivered` value was `null`. When trying to concatenate `@Txt` with this the result will be `null` and so generate a HTML email with an empty message body.

When it's possible that a given value could be `null` then instead of this:

```sql
+ '<td align="center">' + [Delievered] + '</td>'
```

You can protect against a null result by using the [ISNULL() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql), e.g.:

```sql
+ '<td align="center">' + isnull([Delievered], '') + '</td>'
```